# Partitioning disc without administrative rights in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

We have company laptops with Windows 7 installed, without administrative rights. For the purpose of booting another Winddows 7 installation (or Windows XP, if we can find the discs) we need to partition the disc. It only has one main partition currently.

We have our IT department and although they're against this procedure, our management has given it a go for the duration of the current project, and they're not complaining, but they cannot help us in technical matters on this.

So I am asking, is there a way to partition the main partition without administrative rights on Windows 7, and then to install another OS, without losing any data from the disc? Or to boot a LiveCD or something (I don't know, I've never done it.) and then to partition the main ...

Comment: So You are wanting to partition the drive and dual boot your machine? and Why oh why use XP?

Comment: Boot from a GPartEd LiveCD.

Comment: @NathanTaylor - Backwards compatibility issues we have on Win7.

Answer (score 1):

Why not run the additional OS as a Virtual Machine with VMware or similar?  No need to change anything on host device although running the VM on an external or second drive would help with performance.

This should keep IT happy and meet your requirements for the second OS